# Computing factorials efficiently with Python and Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, factorial

In python / numpy - is there a way to build an expression containing factorials - but since in my scenario, many factorials will be duplicated or reduced, wait until I instruct the run time to compute it.

Let's say `F(x) := x!`

And I build an expression like `(F(6) + F(7)) / F(4)` - I can greatly accelerate this, even do it in my head by doing

```
(F(6) * (1 + 7)) / F(4)
 = 5 * 6 * 8
 = 240
```

Basically, I'm going to generate such expressions and would like the computer to be smart, not compute all factorials by multiplying to 1, i.e using my example not actually do

```
(6*5*4*3*2 + 7*6*5*4*3*2) / 4*3*2
```

I've actually started developing a Factorial class, but I'm new to python and numpy and was wondering if this is a problem that's already solved.

Comment: I reckon a symbolic engine should have that, check out http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Oleg has suggested, you can do this with sympy:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

# preparation
n = sp.symbols("n")
F = sp.factorial

# create the equation
f = (F(n) + F(n + 1)) / F(n - 2)
print(f)               # => (factorial(n) + factorial(n + 1))/factorial(n - 2)

# reduce it
f = f.simplify()
print(f)               # => n*(n - 1)*(n + 2)

# evaluate it in SymPy
# Note: very slow!
print(f.subs(n, 6))    # => 240

# turn it into a numpy function
# Note: much faster!
f = sp.lambdify(n, f, "numpy")
a = np.arange(2, 10)
print(f(a))            # => [  8  30  72 140 240 378 560 792]
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could look into increasing the efficiency using table lookups if space efficiency isn't a major concern. It would greatly reduce the number of repeated calculations. The following isn't terribly efficient, but it's the basic idea.

```
cache = {1:1}
def cached_factorial(n):
    if (n in cache):
        return cache[n]
    else:
        result = n * cached_factorial(n-1)
        cache[n] = result
        return result
```

Comment: I'm doing that as well in the custom class I am writing :-)